# How do I get broadcast to work with djcelery+ghettoq

Tags: django, celery

I am using djcelery 2.1.4 with ghettoq 0.4.5 and django 1.2.3 and I am able to run tasks all day long, but when I try to use any broadcast functionality it fails without errors. Take the simplest case -- I run celeryd:

```
python manage.py celeryd
```

The daemon starts and I try to run a ping:

```
>>> from celery.task.control import ping
>>> ping()
[]
```

I can see the message that ping created appear in the database, but apparently none of the nodes are picking it up? Am I doing something wrong here? Does broadcast not work with ghettoq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broadcast is not supported by ghettoq.

The next Celery version (2.2) will support broadcast for Redis.  Adding support for database
should be simple then.